# Animating dimensions of a div using transform instead of width/height for GPU acceleration

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

From https://engineering.gosquared.com/optimising-60fps-everywhere-in-javascript:

> It’s worth noting also that if you’re aiming for smooth animations on mobile devices, you should aim wherever possible to only animate properties like `transform` and `opacity` that can be animated entirely using GPU acceleration. Mobile devices’ processors are, as a rule, pretty terrible in comparison to their GPUs. As a result it’s best to avoid animating width or height or other such properties. With a little extra effort it’s usually possible to (for example) animate an element’s `transform` inside another element with `overflow: hidden` to achieve the same effect as changing its dimensions.

That sounds really clever, but I'm not exactly sure what they're talking about, and I haven't found any explanations. How, exactly, might one be able to animate an element's `transform` inside another element with `overflow: hidden` to achieve a GPU-accelerated version of changing its `width` and `height`?

Comment: My guess is it's referring to the containing element (with `overflow: hidden`) acting as a mask for the object inside of it. For example, if you had a 1000x1000px div inside of a container 200x200px div, the end result would look like a 200x200px square. Admittedly not familiar with the concept, but perhaps this triggers GPU rendering on a mobile device?

Comment: Okay, so here's what I want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/v9qy5mf4/
The problem with that is it's not GPU accelerated. This is: https://jsfiddle.net/pfxab20u/

But obviously that's a different result. I'm trying to get the look of the first one using CSS `transform` because that's a GPU-accelerated property. And the GoSquared post implies that that's possible.

Comment: It should be possible to offset `.outer` with 50 pixels (when scaled will become 100, thus keeping the top-left corner in place), and scale `.inner` to 50% of it's original size (0.5). For some horror of a reason, if I do `...(".inner").style.transform = "scale(0.5,0.5)";` the text disappears: https://jsfiddle.net/pfxab20u/1/

Comment: I disabled `overflow: hidden` and found out why the text was disappearing. It's because when you scale `inner` down, it stays anchored to its center, not to its top-left corner. So when `overflow:hidden` is turned off, you can see for a split second that it still exists. I fixed this by doing `…(".inner").style.transform = "scale(0.5,0.5) translate(-500px, -500px)";`: https://jsfiddle.net/pfxab20u/2/ Which still doesn't look perfect, but at least we're getting somewhere.

Comment: Aha. Adding `transition-duration: 500ms` to `inner` fixed it, mostly: https://jsfiddle.net/pfxab20u/3/ There's still this weird pulse going on, but we're like 99% there...

Comment: and also the border became double the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind is to counter effect the inner positive offset with the outer negative offset, which is pretty much like changing both width and height.

Check this example: http://jsbin.com/zacozo based on your code.

Note: I was unable to make it look properly with the blue border, but you could wrap both elements into a parent (grandparent hah!) that has the blue border.